# createShadowRoot makes element not visible

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom

I am following this tutorial on the shadow DOM:

> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/

For some reason, when I call the createShadowRoot function on the element, that element becomes invisible.

Here is my code:

```
<div id="nameTag">Bob</div>
<template id="nameTagTemplate">
    <style>
        .outer {
            border: 2px solid brown;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="boilerplate">
            Hi! My name is
        </div>
        <div class="name">
            Bob
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    var shadow = document.querySelector('#nameTag').createShadowRoot();
    // var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
    // shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode());
</script>
```

When I don't call this method then the code works fine.
Any ideas why it is making it invisible?

Thanks :)

Comment: anyone? :(
Really stuck on this.  
thanks

Comment: Try using `template.content.cloneNode(true)` (deep clone).

Answer (score 1):

**The main objective of shadow DOM is separation of content from presentation. Read: [The content is in the document; the presentation is in the Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/#toc-separation-separate)**

In Shadow DOM `<content>` acts as the insertion point for the content (in this case, 
the text 'Bob' in the element) we want to show . Without this, the content, though already available in the document, can't be presented.

So, You need to modify your code to this -

```
<template id="nameTagTemplate">
<style></style>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="boilerplate">
    Hi! My name is
  </div>
  <div class="name">
   <content></content>
  </div>
</div>
</template>
```

And, try using

```
    var shadow = document.querySelector('#nameTag').createShadowRoot();
    var template = document.querySelector('#nameTagTemplate');
    //shadow.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode() ); // does not work
    shadow.appendChild( template.content.cloneNode(true) );
    // or
    shadow.appendChild( template.content );
```

Answer (score 0):

using pure javascript:

```
// shadow DOM example with <template> and template string
//
var nameTag = function(selector, newName)
{
     var name = newName || document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML;
     var shadow = document.querySelector(selector).createShadowRoot();
     var templateNode = createNameTagTemplate(name);
     var clone = document.importNode(templateNode, true);
     shadow.appendChild(clone.content);
};

function createNameTagTemplate(name)
{
     var templateNode = document.createElement("template");
     templateNode.innerHTML = `
        <style>
        .outer {
          border: 2px solid brown;
          border-radius: 1em;
          background: red;
          font-size: 20pt;
          width: 12em;
          height: 7em;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .boilerplate {
          color: white;
          font-family: sans-serif;
          padding: 0.5em;
        }
        .name {
          color: black;
          background: white;
          font-family: "Marker Felt", cursive;
          font-size: 45pt;
          padding-top: 0.2em;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="outer">
          <div class="boilerplate">
           Hi! My name is
          </div>
          <div class="name">
           ${name}
          </div>
        </div>`;
   return templateNode;
}
```

then if you have this:

```
 <div id="foo">Bob</div>
```

nameTag("#foo") will make the div into a nametag using current name, or
nameTag("#foo", "Joe") will make it for name "Joe" instead.
NOTE: Supported in Firefox behind the dom.webcomponents.enabled flag (about:config).